# How to fix NullPointerException while insert data into mysql using JComboBox

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, insert

While inserting the selected item from JComboBox it show's an Null Pointer Exception how to fix this?

This is for an java swing Registration form using java eclipse and Mysql

```
if    (    gender.getSelectedIndex()!=-1)
                {
                     //g is ComboBox variable name
                String    value    =    g.getSelectedItem().toString();
                sta.setString(4, value);
                }
```

i except the selected item from combobox to be stored in mysql

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check for null before inserting it like that

```
if(value != null)
  sta.setString(4, value);
```

You can also consider this

```
String value = String.valueOf(g.getSelectedItem());
```